# How to load Link images and title info in android

Tags: android, facebook

I have a editiText in which I can type anything. What I want is, when I type any link in this edittext and press enter, it should return the image and other info of this link to me, so that I can attach that link like facebook does.

How can I achieve this, please help me.

Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search in Google gave me [this](https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview).

As you can you see, it is a lean crawler and exactly what you need. You can look at the source code and understand how to achieve that or simply use the API.

Next time use Google.